# Should I say "in the home" or "at home"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it possible to say *in the home,* or we should always use *at home*?

I am not sure whether I can use *in the home*.

Answer (score 6):

In my understanding both are correct. However, they express different things:

"*at home*" it more general and usual. E.g. "*I'm at home.*"; "*I left my bag at home.*".

"*in the home*" means more of like *inside the house*. E.g. "*I left my keys in the home*" (and you are locked out now; *at home* however would mean that you went somewhere and forgot them at home); "*Where have you been? We waited in the garden for like hours!*" - "*I was in the home all the time.*".

I myself would almost always prefer "*inside the house / flat*" to "*in the home*".

Comment: I, too, would probably say, "I left my keys in the house," and, "I was inside the house all the time." However, there **are** contexts where "in the home" might sound more natural. Specifically, when we are not talking about one person's house, but the home in general – particularly in more formal writing, such as safety pamphlets or census results. For example: "Always keep a working smoke detector in the home," or, "Nowadays, more than half of all families have three or more televisions in the home."

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for pointing that out. As I wrote the last sentence in my post, I was wondering how a case in which "in the house" is being sensibly used would actually look like but I couldn't imagine one. Your ones make sense and target the right kind of sentences.

Answer (score 4):

Both prepositional phrases are correct. If someone calls you, & asks, "Where are you, right now," answer, "I'm at home." Some office furniture looks attractive in the home. *at home* is specific. You're either at home, or you're not. *in the home* is usually general. Of course, every rule has exceptions. A television interviewer might report, "We're in the home of [some celebrity]."

Comment: I didn't really answer your question. There are times when *in the home* can be used.