# "In house" instead of "in/at the office"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it legit to say

> Mr. ... is not in house today.

, when meaning

> Mr. ... is not in/at the office today.

?

Because in german you can basically say

> Herr ... ist heute nicht im Haus.

Comment: *house or home?*

Comment: It's probably useful to know that English speakers often use a bare "in" with no object in situations like this.  "He is not in today."  "When will he be in?"  "We expect him to be in tomorrow morning."

Comment: Ah ok, thx for the clarification. I think this might be the equivalent to the german `im Haus` I am searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comments into a more complete answer:

In English, with one significant exception that I'll discuss at the end of this answer, the word "house" is never applied to a place of business - it always means a place of residence.

What you're probably looking for is the adverbial sense of the word **in** used alone, which [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in) "within the customary place of residence or business."  The most famous use of this is in the classic comic strip *Peanuts*, where the character Lucy pretends to be a psychiatrist and has a sign on her booth reading, "The doctor is in":

[image: THE DOCTOR IS IN]

Note that in the comic, the "in" is written on a removable panel that presumably has "out" written on the other side.  Some professionals have a reversible "in/out" sign like this so people can tell at a glance whether they are in the office or not.

As the definition says, this usage of **in** applies to either a place of residence or business.  A door-to-door salesman might ask a child who answers the door, "Are your parents in?"  Likewise, if you're at a place of business and are looking for a particular person, you could ask, "Is Mr. Smith in today?"

**The significant exception**: the set phrase [in-house](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-house), usually hyphenated, has a special meaning of "within the company."  It is used to describe either a person's permanent job or the location of a particular activity. Examples:

> 1. Mary is our in-house lawyer.

This does **not** mean that Mary is at work today: I could easily say this when Mary is on vacation.  What it means is that Mary is employed full-time by our company and only represents us in legal matters.  This is in contrast to a lawyer on contract from an outside law firm who might also have other clients.

> 2. Should we shoot the video in-house or hire a production company?

Here, "in-house" means using our own company's equipment and staff, as opposed to an external production company specifically hired for this project.

Note that you would never say "Is he in-house?" to ask whether someone is present at work today.  The question "Is he in-house?" would be interpreted as "Is he permanently employed here (as opposed to being a temporary contractor)?"

Answer (score 0):

While *house and office* may share the same structure, *home* is an entirely different word! Compare -

> He's not at house

**but**

> He's not *home.*

Why? Because **here,** the word *'home'* serves as an place adverb. Similar to the word *'there'* for which we don't use any preposition. `He's not there.`

However, if you are using 'home' as a *noun,* then it may serve as any other noun like 'office or house.' So, to answer your question, it's possible to say =

> He's not at home *(n)*

Now, the major difference - in house/at house

Mostly yes, they mean the same thing unless you get into the nuance of NAmE or BrE.

I had learned that if you want to emphasize merely a *place,'* you write *'at,'* but if you want to show some purpose, you write *'in.'*

> I'm at school *(just serving the purpose of being present at that place)*. 
>  I'm in school *(maybe a routine and you go there to learn).*

So, you *as a father* could be **at** your kid's school. But your kid, being a student, is ***in*** school.

[More on *in or at* home is here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39798/should-i-say-in-the-home-or-at-home)

Comment: Thx for the explanation, but my problem isn't about distinguishing between `home` and `house`. My question is, can I say `somebody is in house` as a replacement for `somebody is in/at the office`?

Comment: @KaiHartmann - No, in English, the word "house" only means a dwelling place and cannot be used to talk about someone being out of the office. Reasonable alternatives would be, "He's not in the office today," or "He's not in today." (The latter can be used for the office or at home.)